# Angular filter doesnt return the expected result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter this json by the first name. I am expecting the result to be A1, but I am doing something wrong.

```
$filter('filter')('[{ "ID": 1, "FirstName": "A1", "L1": "Sabrina" }, { "ID": 2, "FirstName": "A2", "LastName": "L2" }]', 'A1');
```

Comment: I'm just going to assume you clicked submit too quickly and wait this one out before I -1

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `$filter` with pure JSON.

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[{ "ID": 1, "FirstName": "A1", "L1": "Sabrina" }, { "ID": 2, "FirstName": "A2", "LastName": "L2" }]');
var a1  = $filter('filter')(arr, 'A1');
```

Returns the expected result.